# Moving root partition to a new drive, how do I mount both drives?

Tags: arch-linux, rsync, move-partition

I currently have my root partition on a 480GB Sata SSD. I recently bought a new NVME 2TB drive which I would like to boot off of.

Using Arch Linux btw. What I plan to do is the following:

- Create a partition table on the new drive, with the same partition layout as the current boot drive (EFI, Swap, /)
- Backup as necessary
- Boot into a live Arch USB environment.
- Mount both drives, use rsync to copy the old root partition to the new root partition on the new drive.
- Recreate boot partition as necessary following the arch install guide.

Where I am stuck is on the 4th step, where do I mount the drives? When installing arch, usually you mount the drive you want to install to to `/mnt`, but what about the secondary drive, where do I mount that? Should I instead mount the drives to something like `/mnt/new` and `/mnt/old`?

I have read the appropriate arch wiki articles, but they don't mention how/where to mount each drive before actually copying the data.

Comment: This will sound bizarre, but in this case, we need to know what filesystem you are using. Since you're going from a smaller to a larger file system, you can probably just use dd to copy one to the other, but that only works in some cases. Also, you'd need to partition for stuff like /boot and /swap

Comment: Are you keeping both drives installed? You cannot have duplicate UUIDs or GUIDs if gpt which if UEFI it should be.Often better to just do new install, & restore all data & settings from your normal backup.

Answer (score 0):

> where do I mount the drives?

Since you are running the commands yourself, at a terminal, you can mount the drives where ever you want.  Just make sure you adjust commands to refer to the correct devices and mount points.

```
mkdir -p /mnt/old /mnt/new
mount [options] /dev/sdX# /mnt/old
mount [options] /dev/nvme#n#p# /mnt/new
rsync [options] /mnt/old/ /mnt/new/
```